# What is the default value of maxResults in contacts API call?

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api

I've read the official document of Google Contacts API version 3.0.
(https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/)
On the part of 'Retrieving all contacts' there is a note saying below:

> The feed may not contain all of the user's contacts, because there's a default limit on the number of results returned. For more information, see the max-results query parameter in Retrieving contacts using query parameters.

I wonder that 'default limit' because I would like to refer to Google's standard for developing.
Is there anyone who knows the number of default limit?

Answer (score 0):

The default max depends upon the API and the method itself.   Some of the Youtube methods only return 50 for a max others return 500.

Unfortunately the Google contacts API is a very old API and not well documented.  If you dont send a max-results with your request then you will get the default.

You can also send something really big like 100000 if it refuses it it should return an error stating its max.